# Qual a origem do apelido “alfacinha”?

Tags: etimologia, uso-de-palavras, português-europeu, origem-histórica

Estou ciente de que “alfacinha” é um apelido dado aos lisboetas, e faço algumas perguntas a respeito.

1. Apelido dado por quem?  Pelos “tripeiros”?
2. É usado pelos lisboetas?
3. É usado tanto para homens quanto para mulheres ?
4. Por que “alfacinha”?
5. Seu uso é pejorativo?

Comment: Não sei que chegue sobre isso e por isso não me vou pôr a escrever uma resposta, mas: não foi dado pelos tripeiros, sim é usado pelos lisboetas (mas pouco, acho eu), sim dá tanto para homens como para mulheres, sei lá a origem (há teorias pela internet), e não é pejorativo - não mais que "tripeiro" ou "carioca".

Comment: A piada que já ouvi é que são "alfacinhas" porque não têm "tomates" - pois, se os tivessem, seriam "saladinhas". Mas deve ser invencionice de gente do Porto...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sim, *alfacinha* pode ser homem, mulher ou criança; e pode ainda ser usado como adjetivo equivalente a ‘lisboeta’, como em “clube alfacinha” ou “a câmara alfacinha”. É usado por toda a gente, incluindo os próprios lisboetas, e não é nada pejorativo. Quando muito será o contrário. Um lisboeta pode autointitular-se “alfacinha” com certa afeição e orgulho. Basta a ver a quantidade de gente a afirmar [“sou alfacinha de gema”](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&ei=c-PEW8PqH8qWgAbWsJnAAg&q=%22sou%20alfacinha%20de%20gema%22&oq=%22sou%20alfacinha%20de%20gema%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...93970.95095.0.95821.8.8.0.0.0.0.113.727.6j2.8.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.1.104...0i30k1.0.CET0BmxuCIU), como [neste post](https://www.instagram.com/p/Bh4B5AHBMy_/) (negrito meu em todas as citações):

> **Sou alfacinha de gema**, filha de lisboetas e nascida em plena cidade, por isso, suspeita pela minha paixão por Ela.
>   […]
>   Sejam bem vindos ao meu país, à minha cidade, ao meu lar, à minha LISBOA!

Tal como o ANeves já disse no comentário acima, também a mim não me parece que seja muito usado; “lisboeta” parece-me mais. É talvez especialmente usado para exprimir mais emoção, como no exemplo acima, e também na imprensa para variar o vocabulário. Por exemplo [neste artigo em *O Mirante* (2017)](https://omirante.pt/sociedade/2017-03-25-Sport-Lisboa-e-Benfica-quer-replicar-no-mundo-a-Casa-do-clube-em-Abrantes), o Sport Lisboa e Benfica (o Benfica), às tantas é referido por “o clube alfacinha”. E este [artigo no *Público* (2017)](https://www.publico.pt/2017/08/20/sociedade/noticia/medidas-de-seguranca-reforcadas-em-lisboa-apos-ataque-em-barcelona-1782835), possivelmente para não repetir outra vez “Câmara Municipal de Lisboa”, refere-se-lhe por “autarquia alfacinha”.

Quanto à origem da designação, o que eu posso dizer com segurança é que é antiga. Já vem neste [*Novo Diccionario* de 1817](https://books.google.pt/books?id=Y89FAAAAcAAJ&pg=PP59&dq=alfacinha&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiBkd2HvYjeAhWlHTQIHdEzAmI4lgEQ6AEIxQEwFg#v=onepage&q=alfacinha&f=false), que classifica o termo como “baixo”:

> Alfacinha […] T. baixo f. m. O que é nascido em Lisboa.

Mas há mais. Possivelmente já no século XVII e certamente no XVIII, existia o anexim **“anda o diabo em casa do alfacinha”**. Este alfacinha parece não ter de ser lisboeta, e num caso não é mesmo. Portanto ou *alfacinha* começou por designar um lisboeta, formou-se depois o anexim, que depois se autonomizou e passou a ser usado mesmo a propósito de não lisboetas; ou *alfacinha* designou primeiro uma pessoa, talvez um certo tipo de pessoa, formou-se o anexim, e mais tarde *alfacinha* evoluiu de ‘certo tipo de pessoa’ para ‘lisboeta’.

Pelos vistos isto já se dizia no século XVII. Aparece “ia o diabo em casa do alfacinha” em [*Feira dos Anexins*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=1ZRFAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA133&dq=%22casa%20do%20alfacinha%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwji1PvSjIneAhVKGDQIHTYhBpUQ6AEIPTAD#v=onepage&q=%22casa%20do%20alfacinha%22&f=false), atribuído a [Francisco Manuel de Mello (1608-66)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francisco_Manuel_de_Melo), mas publicado postumamente em 1875. Para quem seja desconfiado, temos de certeza numa comédia representada em Lisboa em 1736:

> Ay que parece, que vay o diabo em casa do Alfacinha !
>   [António José da Silva, “Amphitryaõ ou Jupiter e Alcmena” em coleção de peças, Lisboa 1747, p. 473.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=HWteAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA473&dq=alfacinha&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiBkd2HvYjeAhWlHTQIHdEzAmI4lgEQ6AEIqgEwEg#v=onepage&q=alfacinha&f=false)

Neste exemplo, o reboliço é na casa do general grego (tebano) Anfitrião. Portanto o anexim não era só para lisboetas. O anexim aparece noutras obras ao longo do século XVIII e XIX, e esta passagem de 1824 indica que era comum:

> […] se a sorte lhe destina por esposo algum Portugal velho daquelles, que não soffrem mulher de Portugal novo [frívola que não sabe tomar conta de uma casa], todos os dias **anda (como lá dizem) o diabo em casa do alfacinha**.
>   [José Daniel Rodrigues da Costa, *Hospital do Mundo*, Lisboa, 1824, p. 12.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=YtcpAAAAYAAJ&pg=RA9-PA12&lpg=RA9-PA12&dq=%22casa%20do%20alfacinha%22&source=bl&ots=9SXT_Lcj52&sig=ytbyFpee7uXDN2FR2qCDOg8OLlw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiXx_-O_YjeAhUrCsAKHV3cCtkQ6AEwA3oECBwQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22casa%20do%20alfacinha%22&f=false)

Agora o porquê de “alfacinha”. Desde princípios do século XIX que se diz que é por causa de os lisboetas “comerem muitas alfaces” [(dicionário de Francisco Solano Constâncio, 1836)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=HM9TAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA49&lpg=PA49&dq=%22tirada%20de%20comerem%20muita%20alface%22&source=bl&ots=HUuVfbhoRC&sig=NyXZK5Bz1NW7rb_wwUFFzzIGmh8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi0jaXfq4neAhWRM-wKHRQbCTQQ6AEwAHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22tirada%20de%20comerem%20muita%20alface%22&f=false) ou “por gostarem muito de alface” [(dicionário de Moraes Silva, 1858)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=HM9TAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA49&lpg=PA49&dq=%22tirada%20de%20comerem%20muita%20alface%22&source=bl&ots=HUuVfbhoRC&sig=NyXZK5Bz1NW7rb_wwUFFzzIGmh8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi0jaXfq4neAhWRM-wKHRQbCTQQ6AEwAHoECAEQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22tirada%20de%20comerem%20muita%20alface%22&f=false), e afirmações semelhantes em obras avulsas.

Não estou especialmente convencido que os lisboetas tenham tido em qualquer tempo um apetite assim descomunalmente invulgar por alfaces, mas quem sou eu. Já em [1874 um autor](https://books.google.pt/books?id=C546AQAAIAAJ&pg=PA251&dq=alfacinha&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjcxefd9IjeAhXTMX0KHZVMBb84ZBDoAQieAjAk#v=onepage&q=alfacinha&f=false) exprimiu igualmente algum ceticismo.

Também o [Ciberdúvidas (2003)](https://ciberduvidas.iscte-iul.pt/consultorio/perguntas/alfacinha--lisboeta/11602) consultou o Gabinete de Estudos Olisiponenses, e a resposta que obteve foi a “origem da designação perde-se”, mas lá dizem “que há quem explique” com o cultivo de viçosíssimas alfaces já na Lisboa antiga e que há “também quem sustente” que durante uns cercos os lisboetas se sustentaram com alfaces.

Entretanto encontrei o [blog *alvorsilves* (2014)](https://alvorsilves.blogs.sapo.pt/dos-comentarios-7-a-face-da-alface-e-150611?thread=488787) que propões uma explicação radicalmente diferente. Dizem eles que *alfacinha* designava uns punhos ou gola de camisa em forma de folha de alface muito espalhafatosos, muito em voga ao tempo de Filipe II de Espanha, I de Portugal, que residiu em Lisboa alguns anos depois de ser coroado rei de Portugal em 1580. Muitos lisboetas finos teriam adotado a moda, e viria daí a alcunha *alfacinha*

Este tipo de punho existiu mesmo e em espanhol chama-se [*lechuguilla* (Real Academia Española)](http://dle.rae.es/?id=N3JrZwo), que é ‘alfacinha’ em português. Mas eu não encontrei *alfacinha* com este significado em nenhum dicionário de língua portuguesa, e segundo a [Wikipédia](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorgeira) o nome em português era *gorgueira, rufo* ou o próprio castelhano *leguchilla*. Eles citam um dicionário, mas é de [Espanhol-Português (1864)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=WBUTAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA1004#v=onepage&q&f=false), que no verbete *lechuguilla* dá como equivalente *alfacinha* e descreve o punho. Não seria no entanto impossível o nome “alfacinha” ter existido para esses assessórios, o pessoal esquecer-se disso, e o termo persistir na boca do povo como designação algo zombeteira para os finórios lisboetas. Com o passar do tempo a designação poderia passar a designar todos os lisboetas e ser aceite com carinho e orgulho, como acontece muitas vezes com designações inicialmente depreciativas.

Comment: Excelente.  Vejo em [figura 1](https://acusverum.es/index.php?id_product=112&controller=product&id_lang=1) e em [figura 2](https://br.pinterest.com/pin/436989970074391325/?lp=true)  ilustrações que talvez mostrem as "lechuguillas"

Comment: Aqui se ve a história da lechuguilla na Espanha: http://opusincertumhispanicus.blogspot.com/2011/11/retales-que-nos-vistieron-los-cuellos.html

Comment: Excelente resposta, como sempre.

Comment: @Centaurus, a segunda é claramente. Eu nem tinha compreendido bem como é que eram. Mas encontrei na [Wikipedia em espanhol](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lechuguilla_(indumentaria)) (confere com o site do Lambie). Mas parece que em português eram conhecidas por "gorgueira", "rufo" ou mesmo "lechuguilla" [(Wikipédia)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gorgeira).

Answer (score 0):

Designação popular dada aos naturais da cidade de Lisboa, (Portugal) com especial incidencia para os residentes nos velhos bairros populares da cidade.

Comment: Na pergunta e no comentário do @ANeves há mais informações sobre o apelido do que na sua resposta.  Que tal expandir e adicionar links e referências ?